# sending formatted messages across TCP connection

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, printf

I have an existing C program which prints a number of messages to standard error using:

```
fprintf(stderr, ...
```

I would like to modify this program so that these messages are also sent out over a TCP connection across the Internet. (Which I have already created as a SOCK_STREAM socket.) What's the best way format the messages like they would be by fprintf and then send them out across the Internet?

Of course, before I can send a message I first need to know how long it is, so I can send the length out to the client first, so the client will know how many bytes to read in...

Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your socket connected, you can open it as a stream using `fdopen()` on the socket file descriptor.  That'll give you a `FILE *` that you can pass to `fprintf()` in place of `stderr`.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought of that, and as far as I can tell, in order for the client to know how many byes to read in for each message, I will first need to send the length of the message ahead of time. I don't think that can be done by just passing FILE * in place of stderr...

Comment: Well, if all your messages finish with a `\n` then the client can just read until it sees one.

Comment: ...which is easy to do using `fgets()`, `fscanf()`, etc. on the reading side once you have a `FILE *` using `fdopen()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you wrap the output calls in a variable argument function (its how the printf family of functions work) and do everything from there. For example it might look like:

```
int multi_log(FILE * stream, int fd, const char * fmt, ...) {
   char buff[BUFF_MAX] = {0};
   int len = 0;
   va_list args;
   va_start (args, fmt);
   len = vsnprintf (buff, BUFF_MAX, fmt, args);
   va_end (args);

   fputs (buff, stream);
   write (fd, buff, len); 
}
```

That way you can add and/or remove functionality as needed.

**Caveats apply for using the size returned from `vsnprintf`, read you man pages carefully**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at `sprintf` or (better) the variant that requires you to supply an explicit out buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it harder than it needs to be.  If you were sending binary data, and the client needed to recognize message boundaries, then yes, you would want to send the message length first, or use some kind of "framing" to delineate the message boundaries. But in this case, you don't need that.  You can just write out the message text to the socket, using an approach such as suggested above.

On the other end, the peer can just sit in a loop reading text until the socket is closed.  If you want the reader to process the text line by line, you can mark the end of each line with a newline character.  The reader can then just scan through the received text looking for those newline characters.

The only thing that could be tricky is that, because TCP is byte-oriented not message oriented, the reader will not always get the text in the same size chunks as the sender sent it. (Usually you will, but it's not guaranteed.)  So your reader needs to be able to handle the case where a single read from the socket might get part of a line, or maybe multiple lines combined together.  That's not a big problem, as long as you code for the possibility that it can happen.